# How to add trailing zeroes to floating point value and export to excel as float(number)?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I had read a file from excel and read as pandas dataframe.

I have to make few transformation in floating data type values.

I want to add trailing zeroes or change decimal places of the values.
For example:
25 to 25.0000
23.3 to 23.3000
24.55 to 24.5500

I have tried changing the values to str and then add zeroes.
But on exporting it back to excel ,I am getting string(text),which I want as numbers.

I have also tried Decimal library, but facing same issue while exporting.

kindly help guys.
I want to export file to excel so need to make changes accordingly.

Thank you

Comment: This is something you have to adjust in the format of the excel cell. For Excel 25 is the same as 25.0000. Changing the cell format will modify how it is displayed.

Comment: @divingTobi Hey thank you for your solution. actually i have way to many columns containing floating values in excel. 
Although its same in excel, 25 and 25.0000 but to change formatting manually is tiresome and was thinking to automate it through python.
can you suggest any way or article to do that.
Thank you

Comment: See my answer below, I basically copied the code from the XlsxWriter documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `df['column']=df['column'].astype(float)`. This would change for a float number.

If you back to string, Excel read as text.

Comment: yeah it does but the changes i made are reversed.

Comment: You can too put decimal=',' or '.' (depends on your region) when you did df.to_excel. Maybe this can help too.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([25, 23.3, 24.55])
s.map('{:.4f}'.format)
Out[1]: 
0    25.0000
1    23.3000
2    24.5500
dtype: object
```

Comment: i tried this , on exporting to excel it is giving str or text instead of float values

Comment: That's the default setting in excel, not in data. Microsoft Excel automatically removes leading as well as trailing zeros [after a decimal point](https://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-Excel-from-Removing-Leading-%26-Trailing-Zeros).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': [25, 23.3, 24.55], 'col2': [17.3, 18.5, 17.27]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The float_format argument in to_csv allows you to format the floating point data however you wish.

```
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', float_format='%.4f')
```

Comment: actually i want to export as excel, can i do same for to_excel?

Comment: Yes, I've updated it to show you for Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [XlsxWriter documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) for more details. Basically the code you will need will be along these lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [i*0.1*math.pi for i in range(10)]})

print(df)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("file.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")
book = writer.book
sheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format1 = book.add_format({'num_format': '#,####0.0000'})
cols = ['A', 'B', 'K', 'L']
for c in cols:
    sheet.set_column(f"{c}:{c}", 18, format1)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Hey Thank you,
Even I am working on same solution. The issue i m having with this is , i want to  write it for around 40 columns.
So on writing
`sheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format1)`
this line multiple lines , I am trying to loop through it. Can you suggest how that can be done??

Comment: Hi @somya_chaturvedi1 - I have modified the code to apply the format to columns A, B, K, and L: List the columns you want to modify in the `cols` list, and the loop through that list. I used an f-string to create the "A:A", "B:B" etc. used in `set_column`.

Comment: thank you so much. this is what i was looking for. will try this quickly. thank you

Comment: thanks a lot @somya_chaturvedi1 - would you mind marking the answer as correct?